# How does a hamburger dropdown menu stops working?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

i've deployed a web app that shows the location of  exciting places to visit in my home town but for some reason the hamburger menu will not open after clicking on  it in mobile view. i have searched and tried new navbar from bootstrap but the issue still stand.

here's the code where navbar exists.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ghumaune</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=MuseoModerno:wght@300&family=Nunito:ital@1&family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Ghumaune</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/campgrounds">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/addCamp">Post</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <% if(!currentUser){ %>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href='/login'>Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href='/register'>Register</a>
              </li>
           <% }else{ %>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a  class='nav-link' href="#">Signned as- <%=currentUser.username %> </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href='/logout'>Logout</a>
               </li>
             <% } %>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <% if(error && error.length>0){ %>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">  
     <%=error%>
    </div>
  <% } %>
  <% if(success && success.length>0){%>
    <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
      <%=success%> <strong><%=currentUser.username %></strong>
    </div>
  <% } %>
  <% if(info && info.length>0){%>
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
      <%=info%>
    </div>
  <% } %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

the id of the HTML element needs to match the `data-toggle` attribute. In your case, that is `data-target="#navbarNav"`.

try to change the following code:
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">`

into
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">`

Comment: i followed your suggestion and data-target do need #navbarNav inorder to specify the and work on     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav"> as # suggest the targeted data has an id. i also had forgotten to link jquery and bootstrap javascript cdn.